# How do make output have more than one string (Java)

Tags: java

I asked a similar question before regarding I/O using Java.

I'm trying to copy a list of strings into another file.

```
package file;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;

public class File {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

                FileWrite fW = new FileWrite();

                try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("B:\\inLarge.dat")))
        {

            String stCurrent;

            while ((stCurrent = br.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(stCurrent);
                                fW.serializeAddress(stCurrent, stCurrent);
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 


                //fW.serializeAddress("Boston", "Canada");
    }
}
```

And

```
package file;

import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.io.PrintStream;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

public class FileWrite {

   public void serializeAddress(String city, String country){

       try
           {

               File file = new File("B:\\outLarge.txt");

               if (!file.exists()) 
                        {
                file.createNewFile();
            }

               FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file.getAbsoluteFile());
               BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
               bw.write(city + " " + country);
               bw.close();

            System.out.println("Done");



       }
           catch(Exception ex)
           {
           ex.printStackTrace();
       }
   }
}
```

But the ending output file has only one result, how do I make it copy everything?
I am thinking buffered-writer somehow needs to be in the loop to write new ones on top of existing ones? But not sure how to implement that.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Please format your code to make it more readable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are overwriting the file contents every time you call your serialize method, because you didn't open the file in append mode. To prevent overwriting, open the file in `append` mode:

```
FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file.getAbsoluteFile(), true);
```

However, this is one case where the solution is probably over-engineered. For efficiency you really should be opening your file just once. Here's an example:

```
public static void main(final String[] args) {
    try {
        final BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("infile.txt"));
        final PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(new File("outfile.txt"));

        String inputLine;

        while((inputLine = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            writer.println(inputLine);
        }

        reader.close();
        writer.close();
    } catch(final Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You're overwriting the existing file every time you open it. Instead [append](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/FileWriter.html#FileWriter%28java.io.File,%20boolean%29) to it.
Change

```
FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file.getAbsoluteFile());
```

to

```
FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file.getAbsoluteFile(), true);
```